# How is there GPE in objects that are on top of a hill?

Tags: energy

What I don't understand about gravitational potential energy is that objects have the greatest GPE on top of a hill and it decreases as they go down the hill. At the top of the hill, they are on the ground, so how is there any height above the ground?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this: if you had to lie on the slope of the hill and have a bowling ball roll into you, would you rather have the bowling ball released from rest one inch up the hill, or meters and meters away at the top?

You probably said it would hurt less to have it roll into you from one inch up.  Why?  Because by the time it hits your head, it wouldn't be rolling as fast (or hurt as much) as the ball that was rolled from very far up.

What makes the ball that was released further up move faster than the one that was released from an inch away?  That speed and energy it has when it hits you comes from the GPE the ball had when it was first released.  Therefore, the ball at the top of the hill has more GPE than the one just a little ways up.